# Sull'inserimento di 'che è' in «Se sì, quand'è 'che è' il caso di usare l'una piuttosto che l'altra?»

Tags: grammar

Supposto che

> Se sì, quand'è il caso di usare l'una piuttosto che l'altra?

sia corretta, è anche corretta

> Se sì, quand'è *che è* il caso di usare l'una piuttosto che l'altra?

?

E qual è la differenza fra le due espressioni?

Comment: Ho modificato i tag a "grammar", perché questa domanda verte sull'analisi logica più che sulla storia della lingua. Riguardo alla domanda, +1: la seconda espressione è di uso comune, ma non saprei spiegare se e perché è grammaticalmente corretta.

Comment: Pleonasmo sul modello di *quand'è che si va?*, forse. Sinceramente *quand'è che è* mi suona molto male.

Comment: Non sono un esperto di storia della lingua, ma a me questo costruzioni danno un forte senso di francesismo (sullo stile della costruzione interrogativa con *est-ce que*, che implementa più o meno lo stesso dispositivo grammatico).

Answer (score 2):

Sì, la seconda frase è corretta, dal punto di vista della grammatica. Il suo significato è:

> Quando *avviene* (è) che *conviene* (è il caso di]...?

Come forma non è troppo elegante, ma può comunque essere usata in qualsiasi contesto (anche se andrebbe evitata quando è richiesto un linguaggio forbito).

La prima e la seconda espressione hanno lo stesso significato, ma la prima è da preferire perché evita la sgradevole ripetizione. Se non vi fosse stata tale ripetizione ("Quand'è che conviene..."), le due forme sarebbero state equivalenti.

---

Una nota: entrambe le forme sono usate, ma nel parlato si tende a pronunciare qualcosa tipo "quand'è ch'è il caso di...", cioè legando insieme le due E.

Comment: Whoops! Grazie, @DaG.

Comment: Non sono del tutto d'accordo. A me la ripetizione non suona sgradevole e, anzi, la trovo forse preferibile perché la prima mi sembra un po' "corta". Inoltre tenderei a pronunciare la seconda come *quand'è che è* piuttosto che *quand'è ch'è*. Per cui sono portato a pensare che in realtà si tratti di varianti che dipendono per lo più dal gusto. In ogni caso, entrambe le forme appartengono ad un registro abbastanza colloquiale.